# create new group for existing site

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom

I am trying to replicate [to add a group to an exsiting site](https://docs.microsoft.com/nl-be/sharepoint/dev/features/groupify/groupify-csom) in PowerShell.
This is where I am so far:

```
$credential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'spadmin'  

Import-Module 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
$adminurl = "https://me-admin.sharepoint.com"
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($adminurl)
$spcredentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($credential.UserName, $credential.Password)
$ctx.Credentials = $credentials
$tenant = New-Object Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantAdministration.Tenant($ctx)
$tenant.CreateGroupForSite("https://me.sharepoint.com/sites/nogroup", "group name", "groupname", $false)
```

At this point I receive the following error:

```
Cannot find an overload for "CreateGroupForSite" and the argument count: "4".
```

This is strange, because according to the documentation, the 5th parameter is optional. But, even if I try to create this, another error comes up:

```
$params = New-Object Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantManagement.GroupCreationParams

New-Object : A constructor was not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type 
Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantManagement.GroupCreationParams.
```

Can somebody please help?

Comment: can you use pnp powershell ? Much more simple :)

Comment: Does this command exist in PnP?

Comment: yep, i can put that in answer if you want !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent command exists in PnP PowerShell.

You can use the `Add-PnPOffice365GroupToSite` command to groupify the site collection as below:

```
Add-PnPOffice365GroupToSite -Url "https://me.sharepoint.com/sites/nogroup" 
-Alias "groupname" -DisplayName "group name" -IsPublic $false
```

Reference - [Add-PnPOffice365GroupToSite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnpoffice365grouptosite?view=sharepoint-ps)

Comment: Thanks, this indeed should work in general, so a good answer. However, looks like my site already had a group attached in the past, but that group was deleted, and only the site restored, thus the command gives an error: `Add-PnPOffice365GroupToSite : This site already has an O365 Group attached.` Any ideas here?

Comment: hmm, in this case would suggest that you restore the o365 group as mentioned [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/create-groups/restore-deleted-group?view=o365-worldwide). Would require global admin permissions. Also, if you have started the process, it does take some time for it to be restored , so be patient :) . If something still doesn't seem right, you can ask MS Support and they can help you in restoring stuff

Comment: Nope, the group doesn't exist anymore, anywhere, not available to restore.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using SharePoint Online, you can also create a group using `New-SPOSiteGroup`.

**Example:**

```
New-SPOSiteGroup -Site https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/siteA -Group "Project Leads" -PermissionLevels "Full Control"
```

**Reference**:

[New-SPOSiteGroup](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/new-spositegroup?view=sharepoint-ps).

For detailed explanation you can refer below article:

[SharePoint Online: How to Create a Group using PowerShell?](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/04/sharepoint-online-create-group-using-powershell.html)

Comment: This is about SharePoint groups, not O365 groups.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$params = New-Object Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantManagement.GroupCreationParams($ctx)
$tenant.CreateGroupForSite("https://me.sharepoint.com/sites/nogroup", "group name", "groupname", $false,$params)
```